# subnav / news toggle

Tags: jquery, menu, overlap

`News` replaces `sub-nav` menu on mouseleave, although it works as expected but if you move over the parent items quickly the toggling very distracting and sometimes news and sub-nav overlap each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/rd9jS/4/

```
$('#nav > ul > li').mouseover(function () { // on mouseover
      if ($(this).has(".children").length) { // if has submenu
        $('#news').slideUp();  // hide ticker
        $(this).parent().find(".children").not($('.children', this)).hide(); // hide other submenus
        $('.children', this).slideDown(); // show current
      } else {
        $(this).parent().find(".children").not($('.children', this)).hide();
        $('#news').slideDown(); 
      }
    });
    $('#nav .children').mouseleave(function (e) { // on mouseleave
          var $children = $(this); 
          setTimeout(function(){ // after a whilte
              $children.slideUp(); // hide current submenu
              $('#news').slideDown(); // show ticker
          },4000);
          e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is do a small re-write of your first event:

```
var timer;
$('#nav > ul > li').on('mouseover mouseout', function (e) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $this = $(this);
    var child = $this.find('.children');
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        if (e.type === 'mouseover' && child.length) {
            $('#nav > ul > li').not($this).removeClass('active');
            $this.addClass('active');
            $('#news').slideUp();
            $("#nav .children").not(child).hide();
            child.slideDown();
        } else {
            $this.removeClass('active');
            $("#nav .children").hide();
            $('#news').slideDown();
        }
    }, 300);
});
```

The `timeout` is set when the user hovers. If the user stops hovering over the element within 400ms then the `timeout` is cleared and the code inside is never run. 400ms can be changed to whatever figure you want, it's just meant to try to measure user intent.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/rd9jS/12/

Comment: Thanks, but it introduces another annoyance: news shows up everytime before sub-nav shows. If I move from one parent to another parent it should show the subnavs directly, but currently news ALWATS shows before the submenu.

Comment: @Nimbuz - I've just updated my answer. It should be working as expected now.

Comment: submenu closes before I reach it. :(

Comment: @Nimbuz - please see my edit :) it should be working for you now!

Comment: one last thing if possible, I need to add `active` class to the parent item, and remove `active` class on mouseleave (parent and submenu)

Comment: @Nimbuz - done: http://jsfiddle.net/rd9jS/12/ :D I just added this style: `#nav ul li.active a{
    background: #444;
}` to show it working.